# determine image file size php

Tags: php, filesize

I have this code for checking max image size allowed: The one below is for 4 MB

```
elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
$output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
```

I don't understand this calculation and approaches from the internet is making it more confusing

I wanted the size for

- 8 MB

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: And second question is - how many bytes are in megabyte?

Comment: 1.`1MB =  1024 BYTES`.2.`size` came from `$_FILES` comes in bytes,.3 so to convert it to `MB` division by 1024 is done in your code . 4.`4096` is 4 mb

Comment: @u_mulder i have specified for 8 MB. should i calculate both the two sides or just one side?  in `....1024) > 4096)`

Comment: for 8 MB you have to use 8192 instead of 4096

Comment: @M4R1KU what about the 1024. does it change??

Comment: @krushiovida No. With the 1024 you are calculating the file size from bytes to kilobytes. Don't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP `$_FILES["image_upload_file"]["size"]` variable return the value of file size in BYTES. So, for check the file size you have two option,

1. Convert your checking limit into BYTES, and check with the `$_FILES["image_upload_file"]["size"]` value. As, 5MB= 5000000KB, 6MB= 6000000KB, 8MB= 8000000KB and so on. (Values are simplified)
2. Convert the `$_FILES["image_upload_file"]["size"]` value in to MB and check.

For me check the value in BYTES. It is more easier and you no need to calculate any thing. 
In your example, the values are calculate into KB and then checking. As, $_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024 return value in KB and 4MB= 4096 KB. So, your internet code also right. 
If you want to use your internet code for 8MB then change the 4096 to 8192. It will work same. 
 
Hope, now you understand the code.